# I have been trying to make a custom shell with C++. It is working but it doesnot work when Pipe or > are given in the terminal

Tags: command-line, c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char exitC[] = "exit";

    do
    {
        char arguments[200];

        cout << "Enter your arguments: ";
        cin.getline(arguments, 200,'\n');

        cout << "\nEntered command is: " << arguments << endl;

        if (strcmp(arguments, exitC) == 0)           //exiting if user enter exit
        {
            cout << "---Exited---";
            // break;
            return 0;
        }

        char *array[10];
        int i = 0;
        array[i] = strtok(arguments, " ");             //tokenizing the string entered by user

        while (array[i] != NULL)
        {

            array[++i] = strtok(NULL, " ");                //tokenize on spaces
        }
     
       // array[9] = NULL;

        int pid = fork();
      //  cout << "\n\nPID: " << pid << endl;
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            execvp(array[0], array);                  //running execvp in child process
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (pid == -1)             //if fork fails
        {

            cout << "\nFork failed!\n";
        }
        if (pid > 0)                //parent process
        {
           wait(NULL);
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: Hello. As written I do not see what his has to do with the Ubuntu OS. What version of Ubuntu are you using and what do you expect this script to do?

Comment: This is a general C++ programming question, and not relevant to this site.  That said, this endlessly loops on a pipe because you're not checking for [`cin.eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) as well as "exit".

Answer (score 0):

UNIX system programming is quite a big chapter.

Obviously you cannot change stdin and then read arguments with main() *argv[].

I am sorry to say that this is not a custom shell at all. And you don't need C++ to implement one, as UNIX standard C is all that is required.

If you are serious and want to learn, I suggest a classic, Advanced UNIX programming by Marc Rochkind:

[buy from Amazon](https:///www.amazon.com/Advanced-UNIX-Programming-Marc-Rochkind/dp/0131411543)

I believe you can find a pdf copy to download as well.